# How to fit Image into ImageView using Glide

Tags: android, image, android-layout, crop, android-glide

My concern is how to fit image using  `android:scaleType="fitXY"` into image using **Glide**.

My `ImageView` is

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Loads image using **Glide** like this

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_image).into(img);
```

but image is not getting fit into `ImageView` it show space on image either side as shown in screen I need it `fitXY`

[image]

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use `centerCrop()` or `fitCenter()` methods:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(url)
     .centerCrop()
     .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
     .into(img)
```

or

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(url)
     .fitCenter()
     .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
     .into(img)
```

You can also find more information at: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling

Comment: how to set scaletype for placeholder ?

Comment: On Android use this:  Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imageSourceUrl)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop())

Comment: Okay, the above answer shows to fit the image with **fitCenter** or **centerCrop**. But what about **fitXY**? Is there anyway to set fitXY instead of any other parameters?

Answer (score 79):

On Glide v4 you have to create a RequestOptions object, like this:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
options.centerCrop();

Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(url)
    .apply(options)
    .into(imageView);
```

[More info](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transformations.html)

Comment: The result of options.centerCrop() is ignored

Comment: Also as a more succinct option: Glide.with(fragment).load(url).apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform()).into(imageView);

Answer (score 10):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

.....................................

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

AppCompatImageView ivPhoto = findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);

Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg")
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder_gallery)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_no_image)
            )
            .into(ivPhoto);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for my case, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You would use `.centerCrop()`, `.centerInside()` or `.fitCenter()`

Another way to do it is with a custom `Transformation`

Comment: Hi @Empty2k12, can you elaborate on custom Transformation? I have a custom masking transformation but I am unable to center fit or correctly crop the image keeping the aspect ratio consistent.

Answer (score 3):

If use Glide v4 GlideApp instance of Glide:

```
GlideApp.with(view.getContext())
        .load(url)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(view);
```

If use databinding:

```
@BindingAdapter("glideCropCenter")
public static void setProgress(ImageView view, string url) {
    GlideApp.with(view.getContext())
            .load(url)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(view);
}
```

In xml:

```
       <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:glideCropCenter="@{viewModel.url}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to ignore **BitmapTransformation** for FIT_XY scale type.
Also set scale type to the corresponding types like below,

```
        val options = RequestOptions()

        mDesignOptions?.bgScaleType?.let {
            mScaleType = it
        }

        if (mScaleType == Settings.SCALE_TYPE_CENTER_CROP) {
            imgView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
            options.transform(CenterCrop())
        } else if (mBgScaleType == Settings.SCALE_TYPE_ORIGINAL) {
            imgView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
            options.transform(FitCenter())
        } else {
            imgView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY
        }


        Glide.with(applicationContext)
            .load(imgPath) // Uri of the Photo
            .apply(options)
            .into(imgView)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call .override(horizontalSize, verticalSize). This will resize the image before displaying it in the ImageView.

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(url)
     .override(horizontalSize, verticalSize)//resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel).
     .into(img);
```