# Multiple viewType RecyclerView imageView size changes on scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-glide

I have a `recyclerview` that has multiple viewTypes. One of them has an `imageview` in the layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_rcv_msg_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:imgBottomRightCorner="10dp"
    app:imgTopLeftCorner="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Inside the BindViewHolder i use Glide to load the image to the view

```
// I have added this
rcvImageView.apply {
     layout(0,0,0,0)
}
Glide.with(activityContext).load(previewFile).into(rcvImageView)
```

I have programmed the code so the image file has dimensions valid so it fits the screen.
However, when I scroll the `recyclerView` the same image are shown with different size...!!
Why is that happening?

EDITED:
I have added layout(0,0,0,0) before setting the image with Glide, but now the problem is that the moment view is created image has 0 dimensions and the moment after Glide loads the images and has corrent dimensions. That moment all the above items are getting pushed upwards because an already created item changed its height!

Comment: did you programmed it to fit the screen programmatically? or like you did in the `android:scaleType` ?

Comment: No, i use only scaleType in the xml ImageView attributes.

Comment: thanks for this.. please check the answer and feel free to tell if you still face some issues

Comment: How can i use fitXY programmatically in Glide?

Comment: You can use `centerCrop()`, `centerInside()` or `fitCenter()` methods: please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022552/how-to-fit-image-into-imageview-using-glide

Answer (score 1):

This happenes because ViewHolders reuse objects and as you scroll it will show some of the previously loaded images. You can stop this by using `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` with Glide like this:

```
Glide.with(activityContext)
     .load(yourFileDataModel)
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
     .into(yourImageView);
```

Or you can use Signature like this:

```
Glide.with(activityContext)
     .load(yourFileDataModel)
     .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
     .into(yourImageView);
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't seem to work either. ImageViews are not the only viewTypes in the RecyclerView. I have other viewTypes like Video views, Audio views and simple TextViews. Each one has dynamic dimensions

Comment: Well can you edit your question and provide us more code from your layouts to adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the image in the `ViewHolder` to the original size every time the views are recycled in `onBindViewHolder` method of the adapter.

So that when Views are recycled (while scrolling), the `ImageView` can reset to the original size.

```
onBindViewHolder(...)
    holder.imageView.layout(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Source: comment of the @TWiStErRob in [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1591)

Comment: Seems that now i behaves as expected. I will search it further.!! Thank you

Comment: However, this creates a problem onScrolling down because the moment the view is created has height 0 and when Glide loads the image height is > 0 and suddenly all items are pushed upwards

Comment: @james04 just to make sure .. you call `holder.imageView.layout()` before setting the Image to the Glide

Comment: Yes with parametes 0,0,0,0.

Comment: Can you try this `Glide.with(activityContext).load(previewFile).override(rcvImageView.width).into(rcvImageView)`

Comment: Of course  this does not work... Width is from the previous recycler use. And the problem is both Height, Width!

Comment: Yeah but keeping `holder.imageView.layout()` along aside

Comment: So now i have layout(0,0,0,0) and override(rcvImageView.width). Does not work either!

Comment: let me think if I can find something .. also unaccept my answer for now if you wish,, to draw attention if someone has better one

Comment: @james04 please have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025083/delete-cache-while-using-glide#50570725)

Comment: Check the solution that i found. Its pretty custom but there is no other!

Answer (score 0):

Well after a lot of research i ended to make a custom solution because there is no way that you can have an ImageView with wrap_content to Width AND Height and expect from the recyclerview not to change the size after scrolling.
What i did is to have to ImageViews, one for Portrait and one for LandScape and Cube

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_snt_msg_image_landscape"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:maxWidth="320dp"
            android:maxHeight="320dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:minHeight="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/error_image"
            app:imgBottomRightCorner="10dp"
            app:imgTopLeftCorner="10dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_snt_msg_image_portrait"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:maxWidth="320dp"
            android:maxHeight="320dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:minHeight="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/error_image"
            app:imgBottomRightCorner="10dp"
            app:imgTopLeftCorner="10dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

As you can see both have a min and max for each dimension. But the toggle wrap_content between their width and height. So Landscape images have fixed width and portrait images have fixed height. Inside the onbind viewholder according with the orientation i hide the proper imageView and show the other!

```
 sntImageViewLand.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.loading_image))
            sntImageViewLand.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            sntImageViewPortrait.visibility = View.GONE
when (it.orientation) {
    LANDSCAPE, CUBE -> {
      Glide
       .with(activityContext)
       .load(previewFile)
       .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
       .into(sntImageViewLand)

       sntImageViewLand.setOnClickListener {
          itemCallback.onRowClicked(adapterPosition, messageItem)
       }
       sntImageViewLand.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       sntImageViewPortrait.visibility = View.GONE
     }
     PORTRAIT -> {
       Glide
        .with(activityContext)
        .load(previewFile)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .into(sntImageViewPortrait)

        sntImageViewPortrait.setOnClickListener {
           itemCallback.onRowClicked(adapterPosition, messageItem)
        }
        sntImageViewPortrait.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        sntImageViewLand.visibility = View.GONE
     }
}
```